# why does this simple javascript regex isn't matching on the second form?

Tags: javascript, regex

Im learning regular expressions in javascript and i've come to an interesting result

```
console.log("this will be true");
console.log(/\d+/.test("0"));
var hasNumberFormat = new RegExp("\d+");
console.log("this will be false");
console.log(hasNumberFormat.test("0"));
```

this outputs to:

```
this will be true 
true 
this will be false 
false
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the '\' like this:

```
var hasNumberFormat = new RegExp("\\d+");
```

Comment: d'oh! of course, it reads a string, this makes a whole lot of sense now

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
var hasNumberFormat = new RegExp("\\d+");
```

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) Object takes a character string as argument.